# Error in oledb database connectivity

Tags: sql-server, database, excel, oledb, connectivity

**Connection**

```
Conn_String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\UTS.mdb"
conn = New OleDbConnection(Conn_String)
conn.Open()
```

**Query**

```
sqlCmd.Connection = conn

sqlCmd.CommandText = "INSERT into Customer_Master Values (@Cust_ID,@Cust_Name,@Cust_Address,@Cust_ContactNo)"

sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cust_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Cust_id
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cust_Name", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtcname.Text
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cust_Address", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtcadd.Text
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cust_ContactNo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 
txtccontact.Text.ToString

sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
conn.Close()
```

**Problem**

When I Click the button containing the above code it gives me following error..

An unhandled exception of type `System.NullReferenceException` occurred in UTS.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

***The error is n this line-->sqlCmd.Connection = conn***

Comment: Is there any code that initialises the `sqlCmd` object? I don't see any.

Comment: What sort of initialisation?

Comment: sqlCmd.Connection = conn

Comment: sqlCmd.CommandText = "INSERT into Customer_Master Values (@Cust_ID,@Cust_Name,@Cust_Address,@Cust_ContactNo)"

Comment: Is this what you're talking about  ElectricLlama?

Comment: When I searched in `ExcuteNonQuery` to check myself, I found this example first: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx it shows an example of intialising a command object: `SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);`

Comment: Thanks  ElectricLlama it worked

Comment: mark it as the answer below then

Answer (score 1):

When I searched in ExcuteNonQuery to check myself, I found this example first:

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

it shows an example of intialising a command object:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
```